# Invoice lines sum - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to implement this scenario on invoice lines.

Let's say I have 50 products on my invoice line, 40 products are tax affected, and 10 aren't.

So, in the result of my invoice, I have two fields to compute this

```
exe = fields.Float(string='Monto Exento', digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),
    store=True, readonly=True, compute='extras', track_visibility='always')
```

Should return the total of the 40 tax affected products, and this field

```
impo = fields.Float(string='Base Imponible', digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),
    store=True, readonly=True, compute='extras', track_visibility='always')
```

Should return the total of the 10 other products, which aren't tax affected.

Now, I call this from a function, and compute the results:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal', 'tax_line.amount')
def extras(self):
    self.exe = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax
    self.impo = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax

rec=0
```

But it isn't working as expected, I don't know what could be wrong here, maybe it is because of how I'm handling this on `extras` function?

It just sums everything like the total amount of all the lines.

**EDIT**

Following @phillipstack answer, I've updated my code like this:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal', 'tax_line.amount')
def extras(self):
    self.exe = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax if self.amount_tax and self.amount_tax > 0 else 0 
    self.impo = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax if not self.amount_tax or self.amount_tax == 0 else 0
```

But on `impo` field it just sums it all, taxed or not, I'm trying with one untaxed product, and one taxed.

On `exe` right it isn't showing any amount.

On `exe` it should show the total amount of untaxed products, and on `impo` it should show the total amount of taxed ones.

If You need more info please let me know.

Comment: Could you tell us on what model you are trying this? Seems to be account.invoice instead of sale.order? So you try to sum up values from invoice lines?

Comment: Yes it is account.invoice, but this is because the taxes come from there, sale.order also takes from account.invoice

Comment: I'm so sorry, this is on account.invoice, gotta edit my question, You know, when You so much work this things happen, lol

Comment: Done :), Sorry about the confusion, the question remains the same tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an if statement to tell your script to not sum if it meets certain criteria. I dont know enough about your requirements however this might work. Or something like this.

```
@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal', 'tax_line.amount')
def extras(self):
    self.exe = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax if self.amount_tax and self.amount_tax > 0 else 0 
    self.impo = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax if not self.amount_tax or self.amount_tax == 0 else 0
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, well, it takes everything and sums it up on impo field, I mean it should only take result from taxed products on impo, and untaxed on exe, I'm trying to modify it to accomplish that

Comment: You can always update your question if you make some progress but need more help.

Comment: Cool, gonna do it, Thank You very much

Comment: @phillipstack i don't think that's right...if op needs more help he should open a new question, so the original question won't loose it's context

Comment: I hear what you are saying @danidee. I am not an expert on the best practice for posting questions or amending them. I have not reviewed the policies or recommended practices. I would think there is a line where on one side you should amend your question if you feel that would provide more context or clarity. However on the other hand I agree on the other side of that line there are circumstances where you should create a new question entirely albeit very similar to the first.

Comment: @danidee How do you know where to draw that line?